# Function SumIf help needed

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have an Excel report that pulls a bunch of call logs from our call system and I'm trying to create a formula that sums up the inbound calling time for each of our agents for TODAY's date.

- I column contains the dates.
- K column contains the call time.
- L column contains the agent name.
- M column shows whether the call is an inbound or outbound call.

[image]

Using the following, I can get the total number of inbound calls per agent for TODAY's date:

```
=COUNTIFS(I:I,TODAY(),M:M,"Inbound",L:L,"Bob")
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get the total number of inbound call time for each agent for TODAY's date.

Note that the K column is formatted as TIME, so the following will not work:

```
=SUM(K2:K4)
```

BUT the following will work:

```
{=SUM(Value(K2:K4))}
```

I've tried the following:

```
{=SUMIFS(Value(K:K),I:I,TODAY(),M:M,"Inbound",L:L,"Bob")}
```

But it just throws errors at me.

Comment: Have you tried building the sumifs step by step so you see each step work? Otherwise stated as which bit is causing the error...

Comment: Yes, I have. The part that is failing is the "Value(K:K)" bit.

Comment: Have you tried "Value(K2:K)" as a thought or "Value(K2:K2000)"?

Comment: Tried it just now, still getting the error "There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the first character...."

Here's my formula - SUMIFS(Value(K2:K),I:I,TODAY(),M:M,"Inbound",L:L,"Bob")

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some fomatting issue. Can you please share the sample of your data. The formula is working fine for me for below table.

[image]

Comment: what formula are you using? I have provided a screenshot of the data in the original post.